# SwiftUI Tooltip on hover

Tags: macos, swiftui

SwiftUI provides the .help() modifier but it is too small, cannot be customised and takes too long to appear to actually serve its intended purpose. I would like to create a tooltip that appears immediately on hover and is larger, similar to the one that appears on hovering on an icon in the Dock.

Something like this:
[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64193267/189029830-847b329b-e053-49d6-9280-65100e4788e5.mov]

Is this possible to create from SwiftUI itself? I've tried using a popover but it prevents hover events from propagating once its open, so I can't make it close when the mouse moves away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution #1: Check for `.onHover(...)`

Use the `.onHover(perform:)` view modifier to toggle a `@State` property to keep track of whether your tooltip should be displayed:

```swift
@State var itemHovered: Bool = false

var body: some View {
  content
    .onHover { hover in
      itemHovered = hover
    }
    .overlay(
      Group {
        if itemHovered {
          Text("This is a tooltip")
            .background(Color.white)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .offset(y: -50.0)
        }
      }
    )
}
```

### Solution #2: Make a Tooltip Wrapper View

Create a view wrapper that creates a tooltip view automatically:

```swift
struct TooltipWrapper<Content>: View where Content: View {
  @ViewBuilder var content: Content
  var hover: Binding<Bool>
  var text: String
  var body: some View {
    content
      .onHover { hover.wrappedValue = $0 }
      .overlay(
        Group {
          if hover.wrappedValue {
            Text("This is a tooltip")
              .background(Color.white)
              .foregroundColor(.black)
              .offset(y: -50.0)
          }
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Then you can call with

```swift
@State var hover: Bool = false

var body: some View {
  TooltipWrapper(hover: $hover, text: "This is a tooltip") {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
    Text("Hover over me!")
  }
}
```

From this point, you can customize the hover tooltip wrapper to your liking.

### Solution #3: Use my [Swift Package](https://github.com/Flowductive/shiny-swift-ui)

I wrote a  Swift Package that makes SwiftUI a little easier for personal use, and it includes a [tooltip view modifier](https://github.com/Flowductive/shiny-swift-ui#hover-tooltip-modifier-macos) that boils the solution down to:

```swift
import ShinySwiftUI

@State var showTooltip: Bool = false

var body: some View {
  MyView()
  .withTooltip(present: $showTooltip) {
    Text("This is a tooltip!")
  }
}
```

Notice you can provide your own custom views in the tooltip modifier above, like `Image` or `VStack`. Alternatively, you could use `HoverView` to get a stateful `hover` variable to use solely within your view:

```swift
HoverView { hover in
  Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(hover ? .red : .blue)
    .overlay(
      Group {
        if hover { ... }
      }
    )
}
```